# YouTube Autoplay Possibilities In IOS

Tags: ios, iframe, uiwebview, webview, youtube

I have created a webView:

```
videoView.delegate = self;
videoView.userInteractionEnabled = true;
[videoView loadRequest:[[NSURLRequest alloc]initWithURL:[[NSURL alloc]   initWithString:@"website"]]];
```

I have html/javascript to handle the video's loading as well as the autoplay and next video. This all works, but my problem is that IOS autoloads the quicktime - like player, which is also a good thing, but I do not know how to control that, nor do I know how to get the video to play once that has happened. I would like the button that shows up in the player to autoplay. I would like that to happen anytime a new video is loaded.

JS code works like this. I take in a list and that is my playlist. I do not load a playlist from youTube I just make my own list and when end of video is called I load a new video by id. I also autoplay the video which is what gives me the button that IOS supplies anytime a video loads. Also, I am using an iframe to do all of this, with the youTube api's that is how I have control on the js side of things.

Question: Is there a way to control the play via code? If so how, also when the player is already loaded and I load another video how can I get that to autoplay as well?

I found the answer:

If you put `webView.mediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction=FALSE;` in the `webViewDidFinishLoad` then it will autoplay and still let you use the other buttons as well. This worked like a charm and suggest using it.

Comment: Hello rob, can you please create a sample Xcode example to show how you do please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the answer: If you put

webView.mediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction=FALSE; 
In the webViewDidFinishLoad: then it will autoplay and still let you use the other buttons as well. This worked like a charm and suggest using it.

Comment: hey i have the very same problem- the video doesn't autoplay; i tried your solution, still it doesn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: Slight issue is that I do not work for that company anymore and can not seem to find the site or the code. It could be in your js. You might want to check to see if your code is allowing auto play using the youTube api. Sorry for not having access to the code because I could check your code based on that.

Answer (score 0):

To check if the playback is finished I used the following method:

First, set the delegate of your webview to self and implement this:

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)_webView {
    UIButton *b = [self findButtonInView:_webView];
    [b sendActionsForControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside]; //autoplay :)
    [[[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] subviews] lastObject] setTag:1234];  //tag it 
}
```

then start a timer:

```
NSTimer *timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 target:self selector:@selector(onTimer:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

and check:

```
BOOL playing;
- (void)onTimer:(NSTimer *)t {
    id _topView = [[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] subviews] lastObject];
    if ([_topView tag]==1234)
    {
         playing=YES;
    }
    else {
        if (playing==YES) { //was playing, but now not anymore
            //dismiss your view, or do other things.
            [t invalidate];
            playing=NO;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The solution is already in my question. I edited it and found a much easier way to get the video to auto play. Which is to set the mediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction = FALSE; which is set in the webViewDidFinishLoad. This is the proper and most straight forward way because it is not adding or searching for anything in the window/stack. The rest is handled on the jave script side of things. Thank you for a response though.