# iPhone trying to get youtube to automatckly start video

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiwebview, youtube

I have a web page with the following code

if I play it through the computer the video automatically starts, but it will not on the iphone?
can you have a webpage that will automacly start playing the youtube video when it is open???

Comment: where is the hooch ? (simpson ref)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe you can try this in your `UIWebView` put `webView.mediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction=FALSE;` more here - [YouTube Autoplay Possibilities In IOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9433666/youtube-autoplay-possbilities-in-ios)